# Создать и транспонировать двумерную матрицу

Tags: матрицы, php

Добрый день, господа. Мне нужно написать матрицу NxM, представленную в скрипте в виде двумерного массива $a, после чего мне нужно транспонировать матрицу $a и сохранить ее в переменной $b.
Что-то у меня не очень получается, буду очень признателен за помощь! :)

**Обновление**

На этом же форуме, я нашел такое же задание, там парень сделал матрицу так

```
$a = array (
    array (1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9),
    array (4, 7, 3, 3, 1, 5)
);

echo "\$arr = array (<br />
    array (1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9)<br/>
    array (4, 7, 3, 3, 1, 5)<br/>
)";

array_unshift ($a, null);
$a = call_user_func_array("array_map", $a);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
```

но вместо вывода, надо транспортировать в переменную $b.

Comment: @Wahtel, стандартно: бла-бла-бла, покажите что именно вы сделали, в каком месте, вы подозреваете, ломается, где затык.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: @Wahtel слушайте, ну вот тому парню я и помогу.